# How to add edges by unwind using neo4jclient?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

The nodes have existed.
I tried to add edges by unwind,but my function `importBuyConnectionIntoNeo4j` didn't work,

Is there any one can help me?

the data structure:

```
class Connection
{
    private string type;

    public string Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set { type = value; }
    }

    private string source;

    public string Source
    {
        get { return source; }
        set { source = value; }
    }

    private string target;

    public string Target
    {
        get { return target; }
        set { target = value; }
    }       
}

class BuyConnection:Connection
{

}
```

myFunction:

```
    public void importBuyConnectionIntoNeo4j(List<BuyConnection> connectionList)
    {
        GraphClient client = createConnectionToNeo4j();
        client.Cypher
            .Unwind(connectionList, "connection")
            .Match("(source:Person),(target:Vegetable)")
            .Where("source.Name=connection.Source AND target.Type=connection.Target")
            .Create("(source)-[:Buy]->(target)")
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();
    }
```

Comment: Hullo, how is it not working? Just not creating the relationships?

Comment: Yes,there was no relationlationship being created.before this action,I had imported some nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with your `.where` text:

`.Where("source.Name=connection.Source AND target.Type=connection.Target")`

is the `Source` and `Target` the right way around?

Comment: Yes,you are right,so I tried another way to meet the need,Thx for your attention.